# Select and a button in a single row without css react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I have a simple form with a select and a button element.
All that I need is to move it right exactly after select element [image]

The code below is what I return

```
 return (
<>
  <div>
    <Select
      {...props}
      mode="multiple"
      labelInValue
      showArrow
      options={scopes && scopes.map((scope) => ({ value: scope.scopeId, data: scope }))}
      loading={!scopes || scopes.notLoaded}
      onFocus={fetchData}
      placeholder={'Choose existing scopes'}
      notFoundContent={notFoundContent}
      onSearch={onSearch}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={selectedScopes && selectedScopes.map((_) => ({ value: _.scopeId, data: _ }))}
    />
    <Button type="primary" disabled={isCreationVisible} onClick={() => showModal()}>
      Create
    </Button>
  </div>
  <ScopeCreationForm
    initialId={searchValue}
    visible={isCreationVisible}
    nameUniqValidator={nameUniqValidator}
    onCreate={handleCreate}
    onCancel={handleCancel}
  />
</>
```

And question is, how I can move it here without creating a separate CSS file

Comment: Add a `className` to the surrounding `div`, and give it a `display:flex`...should get the job done!

Comment: You can add styles inline (e.g. `<YourComponent style={{ display: 'inline-block', backgroundColor: 'red', ... }} />`)

Comment: @Matthew Johnson <div className={{ display: 'flex' }}> did not fix enything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `display: flex`:

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex'}}>
    <Select          
      ...
    />
    <Button           
      type="primary" disabled={isCreationVisible} onClick={() => showModal()}>
      Create
    </Button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` for this issue.

Keeping your css in the js file can be done many ways. The simplest way is to inline your styles as others have suggested. I would try the following:

```
<>
  <div 
    style={{ display: 'flex', alignContent: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
  >
    <Select
      {...props}
      mode="multiple"
      labelInValue
      showArrow
      options={scopes && scopes.map((scope) => ({ value: scope.scopeId, data: scope }))}
      loading={!scopes || scopes.notLoaded}
      onFocus={fetchData}
      placeholder={'Choose existing scopes'}
      notFoundContent={notFoundContent}
      onSearch={onSearch}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={selectedScopes && selectedScopes.map((_) => ({ value: _.scopeId, data: _ }))}
    />
    <Button type="primary" disabled={isCreationVisible} onClick={() => showModal()}>
      Create
    </Button>
  </div>
  <ScopeCreationForm
    initialId={searchValue}
    visible={isCreationVisible}
    nameUniqValidator={nameUniqValidator}
    onCreate={handleCreate}
    onCancel={handleCancel}
  />
</>
```

Another way of keeping your css in js files is to use a package like [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com/) or `material-ui`'s [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) paradigm.